# Plot a set of points on the face image with a spacing of specific pixels

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a set of reference points on the normalized face image. And I consider 4 situations such as 463, 116, 29, 15 points with a spacing of 5, 10, 20, and 30 pixels.I dont have enough reputaion to post the picture,but you can click my head portrait, which is the first kind of image after placing points.

I don’t want to use something like `for`, because it will be time-consuming and stupid for coding. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: why would you need a for loop to plot points? Maybe your question is too unclear

Comment: I can use a for loop to plot the points row by row or column by column, but I dont want to do so. And I want the points to be well-distributed on the face region, which is used for face recognition. @MZimmerman6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will plot a grid of dots on your image:

```
npoints = 463;
space = 5;

r = floor(sqrt(463));
c = ceil(npoints / r);

x = 1:space:r*space;
y = 1:space:c*space;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

plot(X,Y,'.')
```